# Is there a way to make Angular reflect a property binding to the attribute

Tags: dart, angular

**app_element.dart**

```
library attribute_binding.app_element;

import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:attribute_binding/app_element.dart';

@Component(selector: 'app-element', templateUrl: 'app_element.html')
class AppElement {
  @Input() String attr2 = 'foo';
}
```

**app_element.html**

```
<h2>app-element</h2>
<div my-attr="attr1">attr1</div>
<div [my-attr]="attr2">attr2 {{attr2}}</div>
```

so that both `<div>` get a green background color?

With the code above only the first `<div>` gets a green background.

Comment: Are you getting any error? If it is an attribute, you must use `attr`, like `<div [attr.my-attr]="attr2">...` and should work fine.

Comment: Great, that was what I was looking for! Can you please add this as an answer? In the meantime I found `ng-reflect-` (https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/3072/files#diff-2640bfb99eb7bbce698270f59ffa4226R28) but wasn't able to figure out how it works and if it actually provides this or a similar functionality. But I tried your suggestion and it does what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bind to an attribute instead of a property of the element, you must use the form `[attr.my-attribute]="expression"`.

For more info about it you can see the [official cheatsheet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html) and [Template syntax - Attribute, Class, and Style Bindings](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#other-bindings) from the official doc as well.

Regarding your finding, that seems to be from an old PR (15 July) and see that it's not being even exported, and most important you can't find that const anymore in the latest master (see [dom_renderer](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_renderer.ts)).

Glad it helped.